# Hierarchical routes with react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

If I want to have a hierarchy of routes, with active states getting applied to my navigation, but where certain levels of the navigation are purely logical.

For example if I do

```
<Route component={App} path="/" >
        <Route path="example" component={empty}>
            <Route path="ex1" component={ex1} />
            <Route path="ex2" component={ex2} />
            <IndexRedirect to="ex1" />
        </Route>
 </Route>
```

My navigation node example gets the active states correctly applied, but I then have to create an empty component, which just renders the children.

Alternatively I can  flatten the routes, which means I no longer need to create an empty components but then I no longer get the active navigation states.

Is there a good solution to this? (I'm using the latest react-router v2.0.0rc5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just omit the empty component. I'd write your example as:

```
<Route path="/" component={App} >
  <Route path="example">
    <IndexRedirect to="ex1" />
    <Route path="ex1" component={ex1} />
    <Route path="ex2" component={ex2} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

This would be considered idiomatic.